# When trying to global variable inside google API callback function, variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, variables, callback, global-variables

My code is like this. i am trying to define a variable from outside the function

```
let i = ""
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error,options)
function success() {
    a();
    b();
}
function a() {
    if (x) {
      i = a
    }
}
function b() {
   let n = i
```

**`Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`**

This is where the code fails.
I'm not sure wat happened but maybe a double nest exploded the code?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see this code producing that error. Please post success, error and options callbacks as well.

Comment: Is that your complete and exact code? I cannot reproduce.